# Magento - Get total number of items of a category in view.phtml

Tags: magento, count, categories

How can I get the total number of Items, I want to show it in the category view.phtml file. Usually this value is in the Toolbar.phtml.

I have tried something like this, but I think I am pretty far away:

> $this->helper('catalog/output')->$_productCollection->count()

Magento version 1.7.0.2

The expected result should be something like this:

Items in this category: **17**
The 17 should be the total number.  If possible should include subcategory items.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that you want to display it in view.phtml you already have the current category object there so you can use `$_category->getId()`

```
 $products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())
 ->getProductCount();

echo($products_count);
```

If you want to use it in list.phtml you can use

```
echo($_productCollection->count());
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this,

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');?>
<?php $_category_detail = Mage::registry('current_category');?>
<?php $_category_detail->getName();?>
<?php $_category_detail->getId(); ?>

<?php $products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_detail->getId())
        ->getProductCount();
echo($products_count);
?>
```

Comment: Perfect solution . Thanks .

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you can't show the total amount of filtered items in your view.phtml.
the reason is, that the logic, which gets the total amount, is not present in the **$this** context of the **view.phtml**.
But the logic is available in the **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar** block which is a child block of **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List**, though.

that basically means that you can actually get the total amount of filtered items by instantiating a toolbar and list block.
After doing that, the collection of the toolbar block has to be set with the value of the collection of the list block.

the following code is used in the **view.phtml** file to get the **filtered** total amount of items from the toolbar block:

```
$toolbar = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar();
$list = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List();
$toolbar-> setCollection($list -> getLoadedProductCollection());
$products_count = $toolbar -> getTotalNum();
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be two ways we can find product count of a category.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('level')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id');

foreach($collection as $cat)
    $cat->getProductCount();
```

This will give you the product count for deepest category only. So for example, you have following categories. considering tree like structure.

Clothes(6)
  ->Cotton(3)
     ->Women(2)

The result returned from the piece of code given above.
Clothes(3)
Cotton(1)
Women(2)

There are three products directly associated with Clothes only, 1 with Cotton only and 2 with Women only. So it simply ignores the subcategories.

Another way is getting product count from products perspective.

```
$current_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat->getEntityId());

$productCount = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('manufacturer',$this->manufacturer["id"])
                ->addFieldToFilter('visibility',4)
                ->addFieldToFilter('status',1)
                ->addCategoryFilter($current_category)->getSize();
```

This gives us the added benefit of filtering product attributes. However in the above scenario, the count returned will be slightly different.

It will return Clothes (6), as it has 3 products associated to itself and 3 more products to its sub categories. Similarly
Cotton(3)
Women(2).

So for efficient results it would be nice to use mix of both.

Answer (score 1):

It's not right to load additional model inside view because you already have model instance from which you can retrieve Product collection.

```
 $this->getCurrentCategory()->getProductCollection()->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple and it worked well for me its just one line of code

```
<?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getProductCount();?>
```

It will display the count of the products of current category